# defining a function xGreenBottles

Tags: java

I wanted to know how would I define a function `xGreenBottles` that would when given an input x, will produce and return the words for the song for a given value of xGreenBottles e.g. starting with x green bottles and removing 1 green bottle everytime using a loop.

This my code so far

```
public class TenGreenBottles
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

       int bottles = 10; 

       while(bottles>1)
       {
           System.out.println(+ bottles + " green bottles standing on the wall");
           System.out.println(+ bottles + " green bottles standing on the wall");
           System.out.println("and if 1 green bottle should accidently fall, ");
           System.out.println("there'll be " + (bottles-1) + " green bottles standing on the wall.");
           System.out.println(" "); 

           bottles = bottles - 1; 
       }
        System.out.println(+ bottles + " green bottle, standing on the wall,");
        System.out.println(+ bottles + " green bottle, standing on the wall,");
        System.out.println("and if 1 green bottle, should accidently fall,");
        System.out.println("there'll be no green bottles, standing on the wall");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: How would I  define a function called xGreenBottles? That would when given an input x, will produce and return the words for the song for a given value of xGreenBottles e.g. starting with x green bottles and removing 1 green bottle everytime using a loop.

Comment: Note that very basic beginner questions such as this one are easily searchable on Google. You'll probably receive downvotes on the question, "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*" (*for this site*)

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this site..

Answer (score 1):

Make a function like this:

```
public void xGreenBottles(int bottles) {
    // Your code from main minus your line "int bottles = 10;""
}
```

Call the function like

```
xGreenBottles(10);
```

in your main method to do what you want.